# how to set image layout param in Gallery in android

Tags: android, gallery

I want to use gallery in android so in adapter class I have set

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
        iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
        iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        //iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return iView;
    }
```

So it overlap all my image, it does not show properly one by one.

but if I set

```
iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,150));
```

then it does not overlap image but image size will increase..
So What I have to do if I want to wrap content of image height width

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at gallery doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html
You can use "setSpacing" method on gallery object to force images not to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably look at using `dp` in your layout. This would involve some scaling but it would make you app compatible over devices.

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) ( DP_VALUE * scale + 0.5f);
iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(pixels, pixels));
```

You can choose an appropriate value for `DP_VALUE` through hit and trial.